# Rails URL Generation Error but route exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Making a basic phonebook app and made some changes while figuring out the has_many and belongs_to relationships. I must have broke something because I have no idea why I'm getting this error. When I access my root, I get the following-->

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ContactsController#index
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contacts"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The error shows mistakes in lines:

```
app/views/contacts/index.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_contacts_index_html_erb___2771775118522806317_70170309989460'
app/views/contacts/index.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_contacts_index_html_erb___2771775118522806317_70170309989460'
```

This is my contacts/index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<% if user_signed_in? %>

  <h1>Listing Contacts</h1>
    <% @contacts = current_user.contacts %>
      <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
        <div class="link row clearfix">
          <h2>
            <%= link_to contact.name, contact_path %> 
          </h2>
        </div>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "New Contact", new_contact_path %>

<% else %>
  <h5> Welcome. Make an account or sign in above! </h5>
<% end %>
```

This is my config/routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :controllers
  devise_for :users 

  resources :contacts so
    resources :numbers
  end
end
end
```

This is my contacts/show.html.erb

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><a href="<%= @contact.name %>"><%= @contact.name %></a><br> </h1>
</div>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @contact.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @contact.email %>
</p>

<br>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(@contact) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', contacts_path %>
```

The output of my rake routes:

```
contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)             contacts#index
                         POST   /contacts(.:format)             contacts#create
             new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)         contacts#new
            edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)    contacts#edit
                 contact GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)         contacts#show
                         PATCH  /contacts/:id(.:format)         contacts#update
                         PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)         contacts#update
                         DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)         contacts#destroy
```

As you can see, I have a route for contacts#show so that's not the mistake. I'm unclear as to what it could be. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the route you are using exactly?  It might help to post the code in the contacts controller as well.

Comment: The root route is contacts#index.

Comment: sorry,  I mean what is the url you are using exactly, like localhost:3000/contacts/? etc.

Comment: It's root route so just localhost.com/ But I think SoAwesomeMan fixed it for me. Thanks anyway for the help @RockwellRice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're missing `:id` from the `contact_path`.

In `contacts/index.html.erb`, change this:

```
<%= link_to contact.name, contact_path %>
```

to this:

```
<%= link_to contact.name, contact_path(contact.id) %>
```

Comment: Any idea why it was working earlier but requires an inputted ID now? Will mark your answer as correct as soon as the website lets me.

Comment: I don't know why, unless you changed anything in `config/routes.rb`. Consider using *git* and commit your code periodically—then you could use `git diff` to compare commits: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff